# When using subscribe inside a while loop, it should wait till subscribe code is complete before next iteration as condition depends on each response

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am currently subscribing to an observable inside a while loop. The condition for while loop is a flag, whose value is updated based on some values from the current response. However the while loop doesn't wait for the flag to be updated (or code inside subscribe to be executed completely), and hence the loop runs infinitely.

The requirement is to continuously make new `POST` request as long it return a response object which has a field `"continue"` as `"true"` and each request should be made using the updated values for `varA` and `varB` from current response.

For e.g. if after 4 subscribe and corresponding responses, if 5th response has `{continue: "false"}` then the loop should terminate immediately making total iterations

So basically the loop should terminate immediately when `res['continue']` is not `"true"`.
However, in my case the loop is executing infinitely and the value for `testLoop` is NOT becoming `false`.
The loop is NOT updating the value for `varA` and `varB` in each iteration as well.
Basically the loop does not wait till subscribe code completes execution.

**Method in component.ts file**

```
let testLoop = true;
let varA = 100;
let varB = 0;
while(testLoop){
    this.someService.sampleFunc(varA, varB).subscribe((res:any)=>{
        //do something with res
        if(res['continue'] == 'true'){
            varA = res['A'];
            varB = res['B'];
        }
        else{
            testLoop = false;
        }
    })
}
```

**Method in service.ts file**

```
sampleFunc(varA: number, varB: number){
    return this.http.post(url,{
        varA: varA,
        varB: varB
    })
}
```

**sample response from POST method**

```
{
    count: 100,
    varA: 10,
    varB: 10,
    continue: "true"
}
```

I had gone through multiple threads suggesting different `rxjs` operators, but could not find a solution which suits the above mentioned use case.

- **Updated with additional details**

There was requirement which was missed. From each subscribe result, I also need to append to an array `finalValues` and use that array once the loop finshes executing.

The code in **component.ts** would now look like:

```
let testLoop = true;
let varA = 100;
let varB = 0;
let finalValues = [];
while(testLoop){
    this.someService.sampleFunc(varA, varB).subscribe((res:any)=>{
        finalValues = finalValues.concat(res['values']);
        if(res['continue'] == 'true'){
            varA = res['A'];
            varB = res['B'];
        }
        else{
            testLoop = false;
        }
    })
}
```

**sample response**

```
{
    values: ['A','B','C'],
    count: 100,
    varA: 10,
    varB: 10,
    continue: "true"
}
```

Comment: is `this.http` some third party library like `axios` or somewhat else?

Comment: I don't think you can do what you're trying to do in a `while` loop. `this.http.post` appears to be an AJAX request which will be async. The loop will not wait

Comment: @LucasA `this.http` corresponds to injected variable in constructor for `HTTPClient` class from `'@angular/common/http'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  obs$ = this.sampleFunc(1,2)
  sampleFunc(a:number,b:number)
  {
    return this.sampleCall(a,b).pipe(
      tap((res) => {
        ..do something with "res"..
      }),
      switchMap((res:any) => {
        if (res.continue == 'true') return this.sampleFunc(res.a, res.b);
        return EMPTY;
      })
    );
  }
  sampleCall(a:number,b:number)
  {
      return this.http.post(url,{
        varA: varA,
        varB: varB
      })
  }
```

Then you simple subscribe to obs$, and don't forget unsubscribe!!

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cua7ei?file=src%2Fmain.ts) (in the stackblitz I use async pipe to subscribe/unsubscribe)

**Update** the instructions under tap are executed when the subscription is made, so in in res we have as response an object with a property "values" we can make some like

```
  finalValues:any[]=[];
  sampleFunc(a:number,b:number)
  {
    return this.sampleCall(a,b).pipe(
      tap((res) => {
        this.finalValues=this.finalValues.concat(res.values)
        //or
       this.finalValues=[...this.finalValues,...res.values]
      }),
      switchMap((res:any) => {
           ...
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: would you able to update the answer to add the additional requirement for appending `finalValues` array as well (which I updated in the actual question)?

Comment: Just do it (and update the stackblitz). See that the instructions under the "tap" are executed when we subscribe.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`expand`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/expand) operator to recursively call a method that returns an observable, then use [`takeWhile`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/takeWhile) to stop calling when a condition is met.

Something like this should work for you:

```
repeatSampleFunc$ = this.someService.sampleFunc(varA, varB).pipe(
   expand(({A, B}) => this.someService.sampleFunc(A, B)),
   takeWhile(({continue}) => continue === 'true', true) 
);
```

```
repeatSampleFunc$.subscribe(
   response => // do something with response
);
```

---

To accumulate the results into a single array, you can use the [`reduce`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/reduce) operator:

```
const EMPTY_RESPONSE = {
    values: [],
    count: 0,
    varA: 0,
    varB: 0,
    continue: "true"
};

repeatSampleFunc$ = this.someService.sampleFunc(varA, varB).pipe(
   expand(({A, B}) => this.someService.sampleFunc(A, B)),
   takeWhile(({continue}) => continue === 'true', true),
   reduce((finalValues, {values}) => finalValues.concat(values), this.EMPTY_RESPONSE)
);
```

Comment: would you be able to update this answer to include the additional requirement for appending `finalValues` array as well (which I updated in the actual question)? also in `repeatSampleFunc$.subscribe` what is the `response` that we are actually getting?

Comment: In the subscribe, you would get whatever the observable chain emits. In the first example, it would emit each time a response was received. The emitted value would be the response object. 

In the second example, the subscribe will receive only a single emission. It will be the combined array.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to make the call and to handle the answer, if the condition to make a new request success it calls to itself again (recursively) if not, it ends.

```
keepAlive = () => {
  this.service.makePostRequest().subscribe(answer=>{
    if (!answer.condition) return
    this.keepAlive()
})
```

}